# SPD2007 workflow loop not working

Tags: workflow

Good day,

I have a Worfklow in SharePoint Designer 2007 that is initiated when a new item is created.
The workflow then does the following:
1. Updates a list item to "today's" date
2. Pause for 1 day
3. checks if status is "resolved"
3.1 IF yes, stop workflow
3.2 If No, Repeat step 1

But this is not working, basically it only runs once and then workflow completes.
Can you please help?
Screenshot of the workflow under the below link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/83deqbbvoylsjnw/Looper.png?dl=0

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is "if status is not equal to resolved", it will pause for one day then the step is completed it goes on to the next step (which there are none), thus the workflow is completed.

"If statements" are not recurring, they just check if a condition is true or false, take action and then end. Thus, a while-loop (or for-Loop) would be used, eg. while(this condition is true){do this}. But from what I know SPD does not allow the use of while or for loops, thus to create such effect you would need to make use two Workflows.

A solution would be to create another identical workflow. Simply under the condtion "Status not equal to resolved" add an Action to stop this workflow and start the other one. This way you create a Loop that will run as long as your Status are not equal to resolved.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Sounds logical...I'll try it out and let you know the outcome :)

Comment: yep sure :) you can test with less wait time and set an output every time a workflow starts to check it

Comment: works great, thank you so much for your support. Was truly helpful and much needed !!